# Why document.write('\45'); let me get %?

Tags: javascript

I've code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>An HTML5 document</title>
<script>
    document.write('\45');
</script>
```

The result is that I get a '%'. Why? I can't understand the code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The character `%` has the ASCII value 37.

`\45` is an octal escape code for character 37 (because 4 * 8 + 5 = 37).

Note that according to the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_Features#Escape_Sequences) the usage of octal escape codes in string literals is deprecated:

> Octal escape sequences (\ followed by one, two, or three octal digits) are deprecated in string and regular expression literals.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash (`\`) is used as an escape character. `\45` refers to the ASCII Code 45, which is `%`. If you want your code to output `\45`, you have to escape the backslash by writing

```
document.write('\\45');
```

Comment: ASCII code *octal* 45 (usually written 045 in languages with C-like syntax, if they support octal literals at all), which would more commonly be called ASCII code 37 (as we usually refer to ASCII codes in *decimal* or hex using an 0x prefix).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

% is ASCII code 45 - http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html
So \45 means "Write out ASCII character code 45".

If you want the literal string \45 writing out, you need to escape the \ character with another \

```
<script>
        document.write('\\45');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

\45 is the character value. 
Like if you would look directly into your memory, the character "%" would be stored as the value 45

Which character is which is determined by the character encoding, like ASCII and UTF-8

Things like A and a also have different values. A is probably the value of a - 26 but not sure there though..

Answer (score 0):

These are Octal values for these values:
http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_ascii.asp

increment or decrement your number, you will get ampersand and single quote.
http://jsfiddle.net/wrd8X/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But W3School is a bad website. Check out this: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @Wei I agree, I just pasted a quick reference to the value chart